# Hashing resulting in negative one (-1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

What is the reason that `hash` never returns -1?

### Example 1:

```py
for i in range(-3, 4):
    print(hash(i))
```

Outputs:

```
-3
-2
-2  <----- Notice this
0
1
2
3
```

### Example 2:

```py
class A(int):
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return -super().__hash__()


for i in range(-3, 4):
    print(hash(A(i))
```

Outputs:

```
3
2
2   <----- Notice this
0
-2  <----- Notice this
-2
-3
```

In this case, both the `super().__hash__()` method is replacing its `-1` results to `-2`, and `A.__hash__()` is doing the same, so we end up with two `-2`s and two `2`s.

#### Usage

If somneone is curious why I need this, I have two classes which are subclasses of int for limited ranges, lets say 1-20 and 1-100. Instances of this classes need to be used as keys in some dicts so they need to be hashable. I was trying to avoid having a nested dict by negating the hash of one of the ranges, so that one uses positive integers as hashes and the other negative ones, therefore being different keys:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Range(int, meta=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__():
        if not (self.min <= self <= self.max):
            raise ValueError

    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def min(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def max(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Range100(Range):
    min = 1
    max = 100


class Range20(Range):
    min = 1
    max = 20

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return -super().__hash__()
```

The `Range` class and subclasses have been simplified, there are several aditional common methods and several other abstract methods.

Obviosuly, my case has a simple solution, offsetting the negative values so that they avoid the conflicting `-1`, but I was curious why this happens at all.